# workflow to email url on a changed calendar

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise

I have a calendar list for verifications in a lab.  If an edit is made to the event I want to send the url of the event in view or edit mode to the list of persons I have in the event.  I can make the email to the people just fine.  Getting the params together for making the url is my problem.

This is the url in edit mode for a single event:

```
SITE/QA/_layouts/15/start.aspx#/Lists/Verificationphase%20Tracking/EditForm.aspx?ID=174&Source=SITE%2FQA%2FLists%2FVerificationphase%2520Tracking%2FOpen%2520Verifications%2Easpx&ContentTypeId=0x01020029128DF4F81BA74190578C700367431E
```

I cannot grasp the 174 for the ID.  Then there is the ContentTypeId.  Is that fixed for this list or is it a variable that I need to pluck as well?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

There is a built in way to send a link to the context item.

1. Click "Add or Change Lookup" where you would like the link to be in the mail body.
2. Select Data Source "Workflow Context"
3. Select Field From Source "Current Item URL"
4. Click OK.

Hope this helps!

Comment: that gives me:Lists/Verificationphase Tracking/174_.000

Comment: Was expecting a full url from this: [%Workflow Context:Current Item URL%]

Comment: How do I take that param and create a text object to place into the email?  I see how I have the ID I need.  Thank you.